# Does TFS Upgrade take care of upgrading the database as well?

Tags: sql-server, tfs, sql-server-2014

I have an instance of TFS 2017 and SQL Server 2014 Standard on the same box. If I upgrade TFS 2017 to TFS 2018 will the upgrade give me the option to take care of upgrading to SQL Server 2016 or 2017 as TFS2018 requires SQL Server 2016 or greater?

I'm going to do a test run this evening in a non-production environment, but if someone already knows the answer then I can put that time to more productive use like planning the SQL Server upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No TFS upgrades do not update SQL Server.

TFS 2015 can run on SQL 2016, so it would make sense to upgrade SQL to 2016 first, then perform a TFS upgrade second.

Comment: There is a whole article dedicated to manually backing up the data and it suggests creating tables to mark related transactions before the move of data.  If I take the instance offline and do a full backup of every database and agent job I would think I would be safe to proceed without marking the transactions.  Do you agree?

Comment: I quiesce the service, then do a full backup. If you're talking about a pre-prod upgrade, you should be fine. For a production upgrade, I woul always follow best practice.

Answer (score 1):

No, TFS upgrades do not automatically push updates for SQL Server.

If would be somewhat unreasonable if they did, from a cost-to-software basis.

Comment: Also from a support perspective. Although it's not recommended to co-locate TFS databases with other software's databases, it can and does happen. If TFS upgrades SQL server, every other application goes down and potentially is broken afterwards.